# How do I create a MongoDB dump of my database?

Tags: database, mongodb, database-dump

What command should I use to create a MongoDB dump of my database?

Comment: Just a single `mongodump` without any flags and you get ***dump*** folder

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Use `mongodump`:

```
$ ./mongodump --host prod.example.com
connected to: prod.example.com
all dbs
DATABASE: log    to   dump/log
        log.errors to dump/log/errors.bson
                713 objects
        log.analytics to dump/log/analytics.bson
                234810 objects
DATABASE: blog    to    dump/blog
        blog.posts to dump/log/blog.posts.bson
                59 objects
DATABASE: admin    to    dump/admin
```

Source: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools

Comment: To put the results in a single compressed file, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93139/can-i-zip-an-entire-folder-using-gzip

Comment: At mongodb server at which place the database will be stored?

Comment: Please refer to this link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44996506/where-is-default-installation-directory-for-mongodb
@spaceearth

Answer (score 226):

To dump your database for backup you call this command on your terminal

```
mongodump --db database_name --collection collection_name
```

To import your backup file to mongodb you can use the following command on your terminal

```
mongorestore --db database_name path_to_bson_file
```

Comment: What is the significance of metadata.json for restoring?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/113017/how-restore-a-specific-database-from-backup-using-mongorestore-command

Comment: Can it be than stared as a compressed file?

Answer (score 160):

You can also use `gzip` for taking backup of one collection and compressing the backup on the fly:

```
mongodump --db somedb --collection somecollection --out - | gzip > collectiondump.gz
```

or with a date in the file name:

```
mongodump --db somedb --collection somecollection --out - | gzip > dump_`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`.gz
```

**Update:**
Backup all collections of a database in a date folder. The files are gziped:

```
mongodump --db somedb --gzip --out /backups/`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`
```

Or for a single archive:

```
mongodump --db somedb --gzip --archive > dump_`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`.gz
```

Or when mongodb is running inside docker:

```
docker exec <CONTAINER> sh -c 'exec mongodump --db somedb --gzip --archive' > dump_`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`.gz
```

Comment: This looks very nice, but how do you import this gzip file ?

Comment: You need to 'gunzip' them, and then use mongorestore

Comment: says: ERROR: don't know what to do with file!
Gunizpped and tried `mongorestore --db db_name 'gunzipped file'

Comment: typo : "-db" => "--db"

Comment: In version 3.2 of `mongodump` or higher you can use the `--gzip` option to do that: [mongodump_manpage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption--gzip)
and same option for [mongorestore](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#restore-from-compressed-data)

Comment: @r03, Is it possible to remove automatically old backups? For example remove backups which older than 1 week.

Comment: @Pyrejkee: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489398/delete-files-older-than-10-days-using-shell-script-in-unix

Comment: @r03, do you happen to know why template for date `date +"%Y-%m-%d"` doesn't work on windows console?

Comment: @Pyrejkee, better ask new questions for these things instead of a comment. (date on windows is very different)

Comment: How do I restore this single archive? from `mongodump --db somedb --gzip --archive > dump_`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`.gz`

Answer (score 81):

This command will make a dump of given database in json and bson format.

```
mongodump -d <database name> -o <target directory>
```

Comment: And how can we restore all the collections (bson file) in single command?

Comment: Use this command to restore all the collections - mongorestore --db <database name> <source directory(bson files)>

Answer (score 31):

> Edit: Updated commands based on latest version of MongoDB v4.4.2

to export

```
mongodump -d <database name> -o <backup-folder>
```

to import

```
mongorestore -d <database name> --dir <backup-folder>
```

Comment: still work `mongodump version: 100.7.0
git version: 17946f45f5fabfcdd99f8960b9109f976d370631
Go version: go1.19.3
   os: linux
   arch: amd64
   compiler: gc`

Answer (score 20):

Backup/Restore Mongodb with timing.

**Backup:**

```
sudo mongodump --db db_name --out /path_of_your_backup/`date +"%m-%d-%y"`
```

`--db` argument for databse name

`--out` argument for path of output

**Restore:**

```
sudo mongorestore --db db_name --drop /path_of_your_backup/01-01-19/db_name/
```

`--drop` argument for drop databse before restore

**Timing:**

You can use **crontab** for timing backup:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

It opens with editor(e.g. nano)

```
3 3 * * * mongodump --out /path_of_your_backup/`date +"%m-%d-%y"`
```

backup every day at 03:03 AM

> Depending on your MongoDB database sizes you may soon run out of disk
>   space with too many backups. That's why it's also recommended to clean
>   the old backups regularly or to compress them. For example, to delete
>   all the backups older than 7 days you can use the following bash
>   command:

```
3 1 * * * find /path_of_your_backup/ -mtime +7 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

delete all the backups older than 7 days

Good Luck.

ref:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-back-up-restore-and-migrate-a-mongodb-database-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 17):

You need to open command prompt as an administrator in a folder where your Mongo is installed (in my case: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin).
If you want to dump your whole database, you can just use:

```
mongodump --db database_name
```

You also have posibilities to dump only certain collection(s), or to dump all but certain collection(s).

If you want to dump only one collection (for example users):

```
mongodump  --db database_name --collection users
```

If you want to dump all but users collection:

```
mongodump  --db database_name --excludeCollection=users
```

It is also possible to output the dump to an archive file:

```
mongodump --archive=test.archive --db database_name
```

Answer (score 15):

There is a utility called : mongodump 
On the mongo command line you can type :

```
>./mongodump
```

The above will create a dump of all the databases on your localhost. To make dump of a single collection use:

```
./mongodump --db blog --collection posts
```

Have a look at : [mongodump](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools)

Answer (score 9):

You can dump your database and restore with bellow command

```
mongodb  -d <Your_db_name> -o <path of your folder>
```

for example my database name is **tracking** i have dump in dump folder

```
mongodb  -d tracking -o dump
```

Restoring dump

```
mongorestore -d <databasename> <dum_path>

mongorestore -d tracking  dump/tracking
```

Answer (score 9):

If your database is in the local system. Then you can type the below command.
for Linux terminal

```
mongodump -h SERVER_NAME:PORT -d DATABASE_NAME
```

If database has username and password then you can use below code.

```
mongodump -h SERVER_NAME:PORT -d DATABASE_NAME -u DATABASE_USER -p PASSWORD
```

This worked very well in my Linux terminal.

Answer (score 8):

Following command connect to the remote server to dump a database:

*<> optional params use them if you need them*

- host - host name port
- listening port username
- username of db db
- db name ssl
- secure connection out
- output to a created folder with a name

  mongodump --host  --port   --username  --db  --ssl --password  --out _date+"%Y-%m-%d"

Comment: For those who are getting this error after running above suggested query-
error parsing command line options: unknown option "ssl". 
Try to run above query after removing --ssl . it worked for me.Thanks.

Comment: Is there any chance to have an example of how a functioning command with all parameters should look?

Answer (score 7):

Mongo dump and restore with uri to local

```
mongodump --uri "mongodb://USERNAME:PASSWORD@IP_OR_URL:PORT/DB_NAME" --collection COLLECTION_NAME -o LOCAL_URL
```

Omitting --collection COLLECTION_NAME will dump entire DB.

Answer (score 6):

cmd -->

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin>mongodump.exe --db Dintest
```

Comment: Easy and quickest option

Comment: Thanks a lot Arnav, really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Below command will work to take dump of mongo db .

> mongodump -d  -o

On Windows : try this one where c:\mongodump is dump file location ,
It will create metadata in json, and backup in bson format

> C:\MongoDB\bin>mongodump -d  -o c:\mongodump

Answer (score 1):

use **"path"** for windows else it gives the error as:  **positional arguments not allowed**

Answer (score 0):

Or you can make backup script on Windows, remember to add Winrar to %PATH%

```
bin\mongodump --db=COL1 -o D:\BACK\COL1
rar.exe a -ep1 -r COL1.rar COL1
rename COL1.rar "COL1_%date:~10,4%_%date:~7,2%_%date:~4,2%_%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%.rar"

#rmdir /s /q COL1 -> don;t run this on your mongodb/ dir !!!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

take mongodb backup for particular db and delete 7 days old backup using bin        sh command :-

```
#!/bin/bash

MONGO_DATABASE="nexgtv_16"
APP_NAME="test"
MONGO_HOST="127.0.0.1"
MONGO_PORT="27017"
TIMESTAMP=`date +%F-%H%M`
MONGODUMP_PATH="/usr/bin/mongodump"
BACKUPS_DIR="/home/mongodbbackups/backups/$APP_NAME"
BACKUP_NAME="$APP_NAME-$TIMESTAMP"
$MONGODUMP_PATH -d $MONGO_DATABASE
mkdir -p $BACKUPS_DIR
mv dump $BACKUP_NAME
tar -zcvf $BACKUPS_DIR/$BACKUP_NAME.tgz $BACKUP_NAME
rm -rf $BACKUP_NAME
find /home/mongodbbackups/backups/test/ -mindepth 1 -mtime +7 -delete
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Use -v to see progress of backup data
    mongodump -v --db dbname --out /pathforbackup/NewFolderforBackupData

 you can use it for restore also
    mongorestore -v --db dbname --drop /pathforbackup/NewFolderforBackupData/dbname

with multile v like -vvvv you will get more information
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a library called [BackSync](https://npmjs.com/package/@ayoubamine/backsync) which helps to backup and sync MongoDB databases (also local files/directories and some other known databases), you can also schedule it with pm2 to run the process automatically.

Install:

```
npm i -g @ayoubamine/backsync
```

Add your MongoDB backup source:

```
backsync add backup
```

Add your sync source (Local, Google Drive, ...):

```
backsync add sync
```

Then, run the process:

```
backsync run
```

Comment: Nice. I will try and contribute to this opensource repo.

Answer (score 0):

I had tough time to dump mongodb database and was able to extract metadata, but records are not coming up for some reason. But, adding --forceTableScan helped to dump both metadata and records from db with all collections - see the script below,

```
mongodump --forceTableScan --host=HOST_NAME_OR_IP --port=PORT --username=USER_NAME --password="PASSWORD" --db=DB_NAME --out=FILE_NAME_BACKUP
```

above command will dump metadata and records of all collections in the db.

Answer (score -4):

mongodump -h hostname -u dbusername -p dbpassword --db dbname --port portnumber --out /path/folder

mongodump -h hostname -u dbusername -p dbpassword --db dbname --port portnumber --out /path/folder.gz

Comment: 1. mongodump - is a command to create a mongo dump along with we need input about specicification.

2. -h represents your mongodb hostname.

3. -u represents your mongodb username.

4. -p represents passsword.

5. --db represents the databasename tha we need to take dump.
6. --port represents the port your mongo is running.
7. --out represents the destination of your dump with name.