# Delete files older than 10 days using shell script in Unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix, find

I want to delete scripts in a folder from the current date back to 10 days.
The scripts looks like:

```
2012.11.21.09_33_52.script
2012.11.21.09_33_56.script
2012.11.21.09_33_59.script
```

The script will run in every 10 day with Crontab, that's why I need the current date.

Comment: Did you have a look at `man date`?

Comment: Do you need to delete based on the filename or the file's modification time?

Comment: i need a whole script:) i find an exapmle but i'm not sure that this is good for that:  find /home/scripts/ . -name '*.script' -mtime +10 -exec rm -rf '{}' \;

Answer (score 531, accepted):

`find` is the common tool for this kind of task :

```
find ./my_dir -mtime +10 -type f -delete
```

**EXPLANATIONS**

- `./my_dir` your directory (replace with your own)
- `-mtime +10` older than 10 days
- `-type f` only files
- `-delete` no surprise. **Remove it to test your `find` filter before executing the whole command**

And take care that `./my_dir` exists to avoid bad surprises !

Comment: `find /home/scripts/*.script -mtime +10 type f -delete` will be ok for delete these? 

  2012.11.21.09_33_52.script

  2012.11.21.09_33_56.script

   2012.11.21.09_33_59.script

Comment: It depends of the date of the modification, like what `ls -l` displays. Are the date the same as `ls -l` ? But a simple test will tell you =)

Comment: yeah it is a creartion date of the script

Comment: So, what are you waiting to try ? =)

Comment: Be *VERY* careful to supply an absolute path on commands like these! Once, using a command very much like this in a cron job, I accidentally deleted every file on my production mail server older than 10 days, which I can tell you was no fun to recover from.

Comment: Make sure you put the delete at the end! I ended up deleting a directory instead of just the files, didn't matter to much in my case but could have been painful.

Comment: Another important point regarding this comment is, it says -mtime as older than n days. There are 3 options that check if file is older than n days. They are atime, ctime and mtime. Please use the option according to need.

Comment: @DSimon Thanks for sharing your horror story to help us avoid our own! I had a few directories to do this to, so inspired by your comment, inside my `for a in ...` loop, I added a `if [ -d $a ]; then...` to my script!

Comment: `mtime` is the most common, mostly FS/OS don't care about `atime` (depends of fine settings in `/etc/fstab` mostlly)

Comment: with mtime, if a file is being used frequently, it won't get deleted am I right ? Why not use ctime ?

Answer (score 26):

Just spicing up the shell script above to delete older files but with logging and calculation of elapsed time

```
#!/bin/bash

path="/data/backuplog/"
timestamp=$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)    
filename=log_$timestamp.txt    
log=$path$filename
days=7

START_TIME=$(date +%s)

find $path -maxdepth 1 -name "*.txt"  -type f -mtime +$days  -print -delete >> $log

echo "Backup:: Script Start -- $(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M)" >> $log


... code for backup ...or any other operation .... >> $log


END_TIME=$(date +%s)

ELAPSED_TIME=$(( $END_TIME - $START_TIME ))


echo "Backup :: Script End -- $(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M)" >> $log
echo "Elapsed Time ::  $(date -d 00:00:$ELAPSED_TIME +%Hh:%Mm:%Ss) "  >> $log
```

The code  adds a few  things.

- log files named with a timestamp
- log folder specified
- find looks for *.txt files only in the log folder
- type f ensures you only deletes files
- maxdepth 1 ensures you dont enter subfolders
- log files older than 7 days are deleted ( assuming this is for a backup log)
- notes the start / end time
- calculates the elapsed time for the backup operation...

**Note**: to test the code, just use -print instead of  -print  -delete. But do check your path carefully though.

**Note**: Do ensure your server time is set correctly via date - setup timezone/ntp correctly . Additionally check file times with 'stat filename'

**Note**: mtime can be replaced with mmin for better control as mtime  discards all fractions (older than 2 days (+2 days) actually means 3 days ) when it deals with getting the timestamps of files in the context of days

```
-mtime +$days  --->  -mmin  +$((60*24*$days))
```

Comment: Hi @MarcoZen. I have 2 `find` and `delete` commands writing to same `$log`. Why does it create three log files with the first two having no content and the last file having the list of files deleted. What can I do so that the find and delete command doesn't generate multiple files?

Comment: @FokwaBest - Could be you created anoher log file ? bcos of the timestamp ? Are u using the above code fully ? Can u pastebin for me to check ?

Comment: Hi @MarcoZen, I had to remove `_%H%M%S`. For small files, only one log file was generated but when the size  of the number of files to delete is large, multiple log file was generated with different `_%H%M%S`. After removing this part, everything is written to one file.

Comment: @FokwaBest - Interesting ... I dont have that problem .. Good that u have solved it. I think you are calling this script several times ?

Answer (score 9):

If you can afford working via the file data, you can do

```
find -mmin +14400 -delete
```

Comment: To the [anonymous editor](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5805137): Which version if `find` has a `-rm-rf` option?