# Bash script that deletes files older than N days but excludes files in certain folder

Tags: bash, shell

I need to create a bash script that deletes all files older than N days in `downloads` folder but would exclude all files in `archive` sub-folder. My folder structure is like this:

```
downloads/
   user1_folder/
      archive/
   user2_folder/
      archive/
   ...
```

Based on [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489398/delete-files-older-than-10-days-using-shell-script-in-unix) I was able to create script that finds and deletes files older than N days, but I would like to exclude all files in `archive` subfolders.

```
#!/bin/bash
find ./downloads -mtime +32 -type f -delete
```

Comment: You'll have to play with maxdepth parameter

Comment: What's your specific scenario? Using mtime (last modified time) could cause problems. For instance, if a file is copied from another location and added to one of your user folders, the change time will update but the last modified time will not.

Comment: @Usagi I want to have a cronjob and delete all files in downloads folder which are older then 4 weeks. Meaning were added into the downloads folder before that time... you might have a point here with modified time.

Comment: @Usagi do you recommend using ctime instead? I found a great explanation between atime, mtime and ctime and seems pretty clear that ctime is the best way to go http://www.linux-faqs.info/general/difference-between-mtime-ctime-and-atime

Comment: Yes, I think you should be able to avoid most all problems with ctime given your situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
find ./downloads -maxdepth 2 -type f -mtime +32 -delete
```

> -maxdepth levels
>          Descend at most levels (a non-negative integer) levels of directories below the command line arguments.  -maxdepth 0
>           means only apply the tests and actions to the command line arguments.

Comment: Great clean solution and it works for my case where I have static folder structure. I will accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `! -path (your path)` should do the trick

```
find ./downloads ! -path ./downloads/*/archive/* -mtime +32 -type f -delete
```

Comment: Works fine unless there are more the 1 files in archive folders. In this case the command `find ./fuel/app/downloads ! -path ./fuel/app/downloads/*/archive/* -mtime +32 -type` will return `find: ./fuel/app/downloads/primoz-rome-sp/archive/image001-3.png: unknown primary or operator`

Comment: Then you can replace the first asterisk with [^/]*

Comment: Promising, but you need to _quote_ your pattern to prevent premature expansion by the _shell_; also, it's better to use `-not` instead of `!` to prevent conflicts with the history expansion feature in interactive shells; thus: `-not -path './downloads/*/archive/*'`