# ffmpeg capture RTSP stream to hourly file

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp

I'm using ffmpeg to capture a RTSP stream to a file using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://[IP Address]:[port]/[URL] -vcodec copy -r 60 -t 2600 -y /[outputfile].mp4
```

This works ok and captures 60 mins fine. What I'd like to be able to do is:

1. Output hourly files, e.g. `capture1.mp4 capture2.mp4` etc.
2. Put the current timestamp as the overlay in the current file (currently
   VLC says something like `LIVE555...`). I'd like to change this to
   `source + timestamp`.
3. Delete old mp4 files over x days old, e.g. keep files for 1 or 2 days

Is this possible in ffmpeg or do i need to put a script wrapper around the ffmpeg command? If so, any examples of those I can re-use please?
This is on Ubuntu linux using latest ffmpeg package and using `apt-get install ffmpeg` to install so it's built from source.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

**output hourly video files**

You can start ffmpeg over crontab every hour [Ubuntu Crontab](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Cron/)

```
0 * * * * ffmpeg -i rtsp://[IP Address]:[port]/[URL] -vcodec copy -r 60 -t 3540 -y $(date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H).mp4
```

**add a text overlay**

You can find more Information here ->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17623676/text-on-video-ffmpeg

**cleanup old files**

Remove old videos ->
[Delete files older than 10 days using shell script in Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489398/delete-files-older-than-10-days-using-shell-script-in-unix)