# How to restore gzipped Monogdb single collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodump, mongorestore, database

Hye everyone, I am new to mongodb I dumped one of my collection using following command `mongodump --db somedb --collection somecollection --out - | gzip > collectiondump.gz` given on the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880874/how-do-i-create-a-mongodb-dump-of-my-database) now when I try to restore it using mongorestore it gives Error dont know what to do with file.

kindly help me I used this way because the answer in the given link got too much upvotes

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2Elw.png)

Comment: What is the error you are seeing?

Comment: 1. make sure mongodb has permission to dump file.

Comment: @RaviTezu 2016-05-06T19:31:47.101+0500 building a list of collections to restore from userprofiles dir
2016-05-06T19:31:47.102+0500 don't know what to do with file "userprofiles/userprofies", skipping...
2016-05-06T19:31:47.102+0500 done

Comment: which version of mongodb are you using?

Comment: @RaziTezu Mongodb 3.2

Comment: Sorry for the questions, would you mind adding the command you are using to restore it?

Comment: mongorestore --db usernames userprofiles/

Comment: userprofiles is the directory where I gunzipped the mongodump file

Answer (score 12):

You can just add gzip to the restore command:

```
mongorestore --gzip --db projectx userprofiles/
```

Answer (score 3):

Okay I have got my answer first of all I converted the extension of my gunzipped file to bson by using command

```
gunzip -c userprofiles.gz > users.bson
```

after that I used mongorestore command

```
mongorestore --db projectx userprofiles/
```

Thats it