# where is default installation directory for mongodb

Tags: linux, mongodb

I installed mongodb by following the instructions from its site. To open the shell I must go to the installation directory of mongodb, and then type

```
./bin/mongo
```

I don't know the default directory. where might it be?

Comment: You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful.

Answer (score 13):

Late to the party but it could help others :
I installed mongodb 3.4.10 for Ubuntu 16.4

I found the mongo file to launch the shell at

```
/usr/bin/mongo
```

I found it using the following commands

```
sudo updatedb
locate -b '\mongo'
```

Answer (score 9):

Use the `which mongo` command to look for the location of the mongo executable.

Comment: That's true. But @Raghu stated that he followed instructions from mongodb. Thus this should work...

Comment: Which instructions? There are several. For example those of MMS ;)

Answer (score 7):

Windows: `c:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4.7\bin\mongod`

Mac: `/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/3.4.7/bin/mongod`

Replacing the 3.4.7 with your version of Mongodb