# Mongorestore in docker failed: Failed: gzip: invalid header

Tags: mongodb, gzip, stdout

I created a mongo dump with commands (as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17655910/4282333))

```
docker exec -it mongodb bash
mongodump --host $cluster --ssl --username $username --authenticationDatabase admin --db $dbname --gzip --archive > dumpname.gz
```

Now when I'm trying to restore the dump with

```
docker exec mongodb bash -c 'mongorestore --gzip --archive=dumpname.gz'
```

I get

> Failed: gzip: invalid header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like there is some bug with using redirection (`>`). So when I changed the first command to not use it, `mongorestore` started to work:

```
mongodump --host $cluster --ssl --username $username --authenticationDatabase admin --db $dbname --gzip --archive=dumpname.gz
```

Some similar problems could be found [here](http://mongodb.2344371.n4.nabble.com/mongodump-gzip-td25176.html)